# python consecutive counts of an occurence with length

Tags: python, statistics

this is probably really easy to do but I am looking to calculate the length of consecutive positive occurrences in a list in python. For example, I have a and I am looking to return b:

```
a=[0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0]

b=[0,0,4,4,4,4,0,0,1,0,3,3,3,0]
```

I note a similar question on [Counting consecutive positive value in Python array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626542/counting-consecutive-positive-value-in-python-array) but this only returns consecutive counts but not the length of the belonging group.

Thanks

Comment: would prefer to use a simple loop if possible but open to suggestions. computational speed is also important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is similar to a [run length encoding](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding#Python) problem, so I've borrowed some ideas from that Rosetta code page:

```
import itertools
a=[0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0]

b = []
for item, group in itertools.groupby(a):
    size = len(list(group))
    for i in range(size):
        if item == 0:
            b.append(0)
        else:
            b.append(size)

b
Out[8]: [0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

At last after so many tries came up with these two lines.

```
In [9]: from itertools import groupby

In [10]: lst=[list(g) for k,g in groupby(a)]

In [21]: [x*len(_lst) if x>=0 else x for _lst in lst for x in _lst]
Out[21]: [0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach.

The basic premise is that when in a consecutive run of positive values, it will remember all the indices of these positive values. As soon as it hits a zero, it will backtrack and replace all the positive values with the length of their run.

```
a=[0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0]

glob = []
last = None
for idx, i in enumerate(a):
    if i>0:
        glob.append(idx)
    if i==0 and last != i:
        for j in glob:
            a[j] = len(glob)
        glob = []

# > [0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0]
```