# Accumulate 1 and Reset to 0 once condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

Currently I have a dataset below and I try to accumulate the value if ColA is 0 while reset the value to 0 (restart counting again)  if the ColA is 1 again.

```
ColA  
 1        
 0        
 1        
 1        
 0        
 1        
 0         
 0        
 0        
 1        
 0        
 0        
 0
```

My expected result is as below.

```
ColA  Accumulate
 1        0
 0        1
 1        0 
 1        0 
 0        1
 1        0
 0        1 
 0        2 
 0        3
 1        0
 0        1
 0        2
 0        3
```

The current code I use

```
test['Value'] = np.where ( (test['ColA']==1),test['ColA'].cumsum() ,0)


ColA   Value
 1        0
 0        1
 1        0 
 1        0 
 0        2
 1        0
 0        3 
 0        4 
 0        5
 1        0
 0        6
 0        7
 0        8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
test['Value'] = (test['ColA']==0) * 1 * (test['ColA'].groupby((test['ColA'] != test['ColA'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1)
```

It is an adaption of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27626699/5811078).

Answer (score 3):

Use [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) if performance is important:

```
a = df['ColA'] == 0
cumsumed = a.cumsum()
df['Accumulate'] = cumsumed-cumsumed.where(~a).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)

print (df)
    ColA  Accumulate
0      1           0
1      0           1
2      1           0
3      1           0
4      0           1
5      1           0
6      0           1
7      0           2
8      0           3
9      1           0
10     0           1
11     0           2
12     0           3
```

Comment: This just twice as fast :)