# pandas Dataframe Consistently falling column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I am trying to Find the **number of consistently falling values**, which form a part of a column in my Pandas dataframe (df), columnname is **"Values"** and the data snippet is given below:

```
# sample data
time    values
11:55   0.940353
12:00   0.919144
12:05   0.909454
12:10   0.904968
12:15   0.867957
12:20   0.801426
12:25   0.794733
12:30   0.770106
12:35   0.741985
12:40   0.671444
12:45   0.558297
12:50   0.496972
12:55   0.457803
13:00   0.446388
13:05   0.430217
13:10   0.379902
13:15   0.321828
13:20   0.298304
13:25   0.442079
13:30   0.634764
```

Note: in the above sample data the values from 11:55 to 13:20 are of interest to me.
I need to report the # of falling values (18 in this case), and then the %age of lower value compared to %age of starting/Higher Value.

I have tried to iterate my df using iterrows
"for index, row in df.iloc[20:].iterrows():" # my starting row being 20.

I then tried to use a temp variable for comparison, but this is not giving me the desired results.

TIA

Comment: Why aren't 11:55 and 12:00 of interest?  They are part of the decreasing series.  And what do you mean by "%age of lower value compared to %age of starting Value"?  Please provide your expected output.

Comment: yes Andrew you are Right, 11:55 To 12:00 are of Interest. I stand corrected

Comment: in the above sample Data the lower value is just 31.7 % of the Higher Value..   I Can calculate these Only if I have the Start as well as End Value

Comment: If you have separate, non-consecutive sections of decreasing values, it would be helpful to update your example data to demonstrate this condition.

Comment: do you want aggregate information on the group level, or per row information?

Comment: @suraj_Blore did any of the answers solve the problem?  If so, do you mind selecting the best answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reproducible example with a function that accomplishes your goal.  I'm assuming you might have multiple sequences of decreasing records, so the function returns the count of decreasing records and the percent of the total decrease from highest to lowest values for each decreasing sequence.

```
import pandas as pd


def get_decreasing_count_and_percentage(df, min_count=7):
    is_dec = df["value"].diff().lt(0).values
    cnt = 0
    starting_value = df["value"].values[0]
    result = []
    for i in range(len(is_dec)):
        if is_dec[i]:
            cnt += 1
        else:
            if cnt > 0:
                percent = round((df["value"].values[i-1] / starting_value) * 100., 1)
                result.append((cnt+1, percent))
                cnt = 0
                starting_value = df["value"].values[i]
    result_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(result, columns=['count', 'percentage'])
    return result_df[result_df["count"] >= min_count]
```

**Original Data**

```
times = ['11:55', '12:00', '12:05', '12:10', '12:15', '12:20', '12:25', '12:30', '12:35', '12:40', '12:45', '12:50', '12:55', '13:00', '13:05', '13:10', '13:15', '13:20', '13:25', '13:30']
values = [0.940353, 0.919144, 0.909454, 0.904968, 0.867957, 0.801426, 0.794733, 0.770106, 0.741985, 0.671444, 0.558297, 0.496972, 0.457803, 0.446388, 0.430217, 0.379902, 0.321828, 0.298304, 0.442079, 0.634764, ]

my_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'time': times, 'value': values})
print(get_decreasing_count_and_percentage(my_df))
```

*Result*

```
   count  percentage
0     18        31.7
```

**Modified Data:**

```
values2 = [0.940353, 0.919144, 0.909454, 0.904968, 0.867957, 0.801426, 0.894733, 0.770106, 0.741985, 0.671444, 0.558297, 0.496972, 0.457803, 0.446388, 0.430217, 0.379902, 0.321828, 0.298304, 0.442079, 0.634764]
my_df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'time': times, 'value': values2})
print(get_decreasing_count_and_percentage(my_df2))
print(get_decreasing_count_and_percentage(my_df2, min_count=6))
```

*Result*

```
   count  percentage
1     12        33.3
   count  percentage
0      6        85.2
1     12        33.3
```

---

**UPDATE:** Updated the code to address percent value requirement.

**UPDATE 2:** The function now returns a data frame with a summary for all decreasing sequences.  Also added a modified data set to show multiple decreasing sequences.

**UPDATE 3:** Added min_count=7 default parameter to satisfy OP's requirement on a comment (i.e. report on sequences of length >= 7).

Comment: @suraj_Blore did any of the answers solve the problem? If so, do you mind selecting the best answer?

Comment: Marked this one Now.. Apologies for the Delay. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that accounts for a couple of edge cases:
1. Non-consecutive groups of descending series
2. Last value being part of a descending series

I've updated OP data to create 3 groupings of descending series (see Data section below), to demonstrate edge case coverage.

The basic strategy is to create named groups for each descending series, and then use `groupby()` operations to compute the desired attributes.

First create a `dec` column that tracks descending series:

```
df["dec"] = df["values"].diff().lt(0)
```

Now make group assignments.  The `assign_group()` function basically checks the `dec` value of its neighbors and determines its group based on neighbor status.

```
groups = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
groups2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
orig_len = len(groups)

def assign_group(x, prev):
    ix = orig_len - len(groups2)
    try:
        if ~x.dec & df.iloc[x.name + 1].dec:
            return groups2.pop(0) 
        elif df.iloc[x.name + 1].dec | x.dec & ~df.iloc[x.name + 1].dec:
            return groups[ix-1]
        else:
            return None
    except IndexError:
        if df.iloc[x.name - 1].dec:
            return groups[ix-1]
        return None

df["grp"] = df.apply(assign_group, args=(prev,), axis=1)
```

^ Note: The `groups` variable can contain any sequence of values - I've just used a few letters for demonstration, but for a much larger dataset some large sequence of numbers might be more appropriate.

Now the final `groupby()` is simple:

```
df.groupby("grp")["values"].agg(["count", lambda x: x.iloc[-1] / x.iloc[0] * 100])

     count   <lambda>
grp                  
a       10  71.403399
b        8  29.830400
c        2   0.000000

df
     time    values    dec   grp
0   11:55  0.940353  False     a
1   12:00  0.919144   True     a
2   12:05  0.909454   True     a
3   12:10  0.904968   True     a
4   12:15  0.867957   True     a
5   12:20  0.801426   True     a
6   12:25  0.794733   True     a
7   12:30  0.770106   True     a
8   12:35  0.741985   True     a
9   12:40  0.671444   True     a
10  12:45  1.000000  False     b
11  12:50  0.496972   True     b
12  12:55  0.457803   True     b
13  13:00  0.446388   True     b
14  13:05  0.430217   True     b
15  13:10  0.379902   True     b
16  13:15  0.321828   True     b
17  13:20  0.298304   True     b
18  13:25  0.442079  False  None
19  13:30  0.634764  False     c
20  13:35  0.000000   True     c
```

Correctness checks:

Group `a` first value: `0.940353`, last value: `0.671444/`, `0.671444/0.940353 = 0.7140339851`

Group `b` first value: `1.0`, last value: `0.298304`, `0.298304/1.000000 = 0.298304`

Output from original OP data:

```
     count   <lambda>
grp                  
a       18  31.722555
```

Data:

```
df.loc[10, "values"] = 1
df.loc[20, ["time","values"]] = ["13:35", 0]
df
     time    values
0   11:55  0.940353
1   12:00  0.919144
2   12:05  0.909454
3   12:10  0.904968
4   12:15  0.867957
5   12:20  0.801426
6   12:25  0.794733
7   12:30  0.770106
8   12:35  0.741985
9   12:40  0.671444
10  12:45  1.000000 # <-- updated
11  12:50  0.496972
12  12:55  0.457803
13  13:00  0.446388
14  13:05  0.430217
15  13:10  0.379902
16  13:15  0.321828
17  13:20  0.298304
18  13:25  0.442079
19  13:30  0.634764
20  13:35  0.000000  # <-- updated
```

Note: Using `values` as a data frame column name is fraught, as `.values` is also a Pandas property.  So `df.values` won't refer to the column, you need `df["values"]` in that case.

Comment: while this Ans is helpful , as my data contains over 8 K rows I need to calculate and report all the occurrences with stretch of data wherever there is a consistent fall of (more than Or) equal to 7 times.   Can we achieve this purpose with diff().lt(0).sum() ?

Comment: just wondering whether the Pandas itertools can be useful here.. (I have never had the opportunity to use it ever)

Comment: The OP wants the number of consecutively decreasing rows.

Comment: Yes, consecutively decreasing Values; their # ; and their Degree is required here. You are Correct JAponte.

Comment: Yes, understood - this answer doesn't address OP's needs. Update coming!

Comment: suraj_Blore see updated solution.  But can you clarify whether you only need the max number of records, as in @JAponte's solution, or whether you need reports on each sequence of decreasing values, as in my solution?

Answer (score 1):

I added two more rows to your DataFrame:

```
frame = pd.concat([df.rename(columns={'values': 'value'}), 
                   pd.DataFrame({'time':['13:35', '13:40'], 'value':[0.5, 0.9]})],
                  ignore_index=True)
```

Using `cumsum`you can create groups of consecutive elements

```
groups = frame.assign(group = frame.value.diff().fillna(1).gt(0).cumsum())
grouper = groups.groupby('group')
```

This is "stolen" from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27626699/5152563)

Now just calculate the values you are interested in, e.g.:

```
counts = grouper['value'].transform(lambda x: x.agg('count'))
pct = grouper['value'].apply(lambda x: x.pct_change())
```

assign and filter out groups with a count of only 1

```
groups.assign(counts=counts, pct=pct, group=groups).query('counts > 1')
    time    value   group   counts  pct
0   11:55   0.940353    11:55   18.0    NaN
1   12:00   0.919144    12:00   18.0    -0.022554
2   12:05   0.909454    12:05   18.0    -0.010542
3   12:10   0.904968    12:10   18.0    -0.004933
4   12:15   0.867957    12:15   18.0    -0.040898
5   12:20   0.801426    12:20   18.0    -0.076652
6   12:25   0.794733    12:25   18.0    -0.008351
7   12:30   0.770106    12:30   18.0    -0.030988
8   12:35   0.741985    12:35   18.0    -0.036516
9   12:40   0.671444    12:40   18.0    -0.095071
10  12:45   0.558297    12:45   18.0    -0.168513
11  12:50   0.496972    12:50   18.0    -0.109843
12  12:55   0.457803    12:55   18.0    -0.078815
13  13:00   0.446388    13:00   18.0    -0.024934
14  13:05   0.430217    13:05   18.0    -0.036226
15  13:10   0.379902    13:10   18.0    -0.116953
16  13:15   0.321828    13:15   18.0    -0.152866
17  13:20   0.298304    13:20   18.0    -0.073095
19  13:30   0.634764    13:30   2.0     NaN
20  13:35   0.500000    13:35   2.0     -0.212306
```

Comment: Nice way of assigning groups!  I think though that the percent change OP was looking for was between the first and last of each descending series - not from row to row.

Comment: Thanks! This can be done as well in multiple steps: just use `first()` and `last()` on the desired column and compute the percent change by hand. Using those functions in transform, you could easily compute the pct change fro every row compared to the first. I'll make it more specific if OP gives more detailed information

Answer (score 1):

I learned a lot from the best answer answered by @JAponte. But it is a little wrong. If values becomes

`values = [0.940353, 0.999144, 0.909454, 0.904968, 0.867957, 0.801426, 0.794733, 0.770106, 0.741985, 0.671444, 0.558297, 0.496972, 0.457803, 0.446388, 0.430217, 0.379902, 0.321828, 0.298304, 0.442079, 0.634764,]`

the result will be output :

```
count percentage
0 17 31.7
```

The percentage is obtained by 0.29830 / 0.94035, but the correct answer should be 0.29830 / 0.999144 = 0.299. So I made the following changes:

```
import pandas as pd


def get_decreasing_count_and_percentage(df, min_count=7):
    is_dec = df["value"].diff().lt(0).values
    cnt = 0
    starting_value = None
    first_time = True
    result = []
    for i in range(len(is_dec)):
        if is_dec[i]:
            cnt += 1
            if first_time:
                starting_value = df["value"].values[i - 1]
                first_time = False
        else:
            if cnt > 0:
                percent = round((df["value"].values[i - 1] / starting_value) * 100., 1)
                result.append((cnt + 1, percent))
                cnt = 0
                first_time = True
    result_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(result, columns=['count', 'percentage'])
    return result_df[result_df["count"] >= min_count]


times = ['11:55', '12:00', '12:05', '12:10', '12:15', '12:20', '12:25', '12:30', '12:35', '12:40', '12:45', '12:50',
         '12:55', '13:00', '13:05', '13:10', '13:15', '13:20', '13:25', '13:30']
values = [0.940353, 0.999144, 0.909454, 0.904968, 0.867957, 0.801426, 0.794733, 0.770106, 0.741985, 0.671444, 0.558297,
          0.496972, 0.457803, 0.446388, 0.430217, 0.379902, 0.321828, 0.298304, 0.442079, 0.634764, ]

my_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'time': times, 'value': values})
print(get_decreasing_count_and_percentage(my_df))

values2 = [0.940353, 0.919144, 0.909454, 0.904968, 0.867957, 0.801426, 0.894733, 0.770106, 0.741985, 0.671444, 0.558297,
           0.496972, 0.457803, 0.446388, 0.430217, 0.379902, 0.321828, 0.298304, 0.442079, 0.634764]
my_df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'time': times, 'value': values2})
print(get_decreasing_count_and_percentage(my_df2))
print(get_decreasing_count_and_percentage(my_df2, min_count=6))
```