# Classifying according to number of consecutive values with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe column with 1s and 0s like this:

```
df['working'] = 
1
1
0
0
0
1
1
0
0
1
```

which represents when a machine is working (1) or stopped (0). I need to classify this stops depending on their length ie if there are less or equal than `n` consecutive 0s change all them to short-stop (2) if there are more than `n`, to long-stop (3). The expected result should look like this when applied over the example with `n=2`:

```
df[['working', 'result']]=
1    1
1    1
0    3
0    3
0    3
1    1
1    1
0    2
0    2
1    1
```

of course this is an example, my df has more than 1M rows.

I tried looping through it but it's really slow and also using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626542/counting-consecutive-positive-value-in-python-array). But I couldn't achieve to transform it to my problem.

Can anyone help?. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: What is expected output if n=3 ?

Comment: Then it should be: `1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) should be used for improve performance:

```
n = 2
#compare 0 values
m = df['working'].eq(0)
#created groups only by mask
s = df['working'].cumsum()[m]
#counts only 0 groups
out = s.map(s.value_counts())
#set new values by mask
df['result'] = 1
df.loc[m, 'result'] = np.where(out > n, 3, 2)
print (df)
   working  result
0        1       1
1        1       1
2        0       3
3        0       3
4        0       3
5        1       1
6        1       1
7        0       2
8        0       2
9        1       1
```

Comment: @Gamopo - ya, is possibble test timings with real data? Because I think this solution is faster

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach:

```
# Counter for each gruop where there is a change
m = df.working.ne(df.working.shift()).cumsum()
# mask where working is 0
eq0 = df.working.eq(0)
# Get a count of consecutive 0s
count = df[eq0].groupby(m[eq0]).transform('count')
# replace 0s accordingly
df.loc[eq0, 'result'] = np.where(count > 2, 3, 2).ravel()
# fill the remaining values with 1
df['result'] = df.result.fillna(1)

print(df)

    working  result
0        1     1.0
1        1     1.0
2        0     3.0
3        0     3.0
4        0     3.0
5        1     1.0
6        1     1.0
7        0     2.0
8        0     2.0
9        1     1.0
```