# finding columns with recurring nan series between first and last real value

Tags: python, dataframe

I am currently cleaning a rather large file of time series. As you can see in the dataframe below, the majority of columns begin and end with some NaNs.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
               'a': [np.NaN, np.NaN, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, np.NaN, np.NaN],
               'b': [np.NaN, 80, 84, 30, 3, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 4, 3, 2, 1],
               'c': [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 80, 84, 1, 2, 3, 4 , 5],
               'd': [np.NaN, 40, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, np.NaN],
               'e': [np.NaN, 1, 2, 3, np.NaN, np.NaN, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1 ,2]})
```

This isn't a problem for me, but: If there is a series of 2 following NaN's  INSIDE the first real value and the last value of a column, I need to detect them. So what I want to do is very similiar to the idea / thinking behind the interpolation method:

```
df = df.interpolate(method = 'linear', limit_area='inside', limit = 2)
```

But instead I would like to get the columns in which there are these recurring NaN series. So looking at the example dataframe above, I would like column "b" and "e" as the output, because those are the only columns who have more than two recurring NaNs INBETWEEN the first and last real, non-NaN value. So I am not looking for a interpolation method, but a method for detecting these columns

Does anyone have a recommendation how this could be done? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using a method derived from the [consecutive count problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27626699/3545273)

Here I would define a function to count the maximum numbers of consecutive NaN *inside* a Series:

```
def seqnan(x):
    y = x[~x.isna()]
    y = x[y.index[0]:y.index[-1]]      # limit from first non NaN value to last one
    # the magic formula (see ref. post for details)
    t = y[y.isna()].groupby((y.isna()&(~y.shift().isna())).cumsum()).cumcount().max()
    return 0 if np.isnan(t) else t+1
```

Now we have:

```
>>> df.apply(seqnan)
a    0
b    3
c    0
d    0
e    2
dtype: int64
```

So to get the columns names having at least 2 consecutive NaN values inside the first non NaN to last non NaN, you can do

```
tmp = df.apply(seqnan)
cols = tmp[tmp >= 2].index.tolist()
```

to get as expected

```
['b', 'e']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is exactly what I was looking for!