# Pandas replacing less than n consecutive values with neighboring consecutive value

Tags: python, pandas

Supposing I have the following DataFrame df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
"a" : [8,8,0,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,4,1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,7,7,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,1,1,5,5,5,5,5,5,1,5,1,5,5,5,5]}
```

i want to normalize my data, if there is consecutive value less than 3 times, changes the value with neighboring consecutive value.

```
result:   
 df = pd.DataFrame({
        "a" : [8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]}
```

currently i make this work by iterate manually, and i think pandas has special function to do it.

Comment: There is no special function for this. You may show your attempt, then we may optimize it for faster operation (if any). Using for loop may become very slow for this for large dataset.

Comment: I think the answer here can help you :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626542/counting-consecutive-positive-value-in-python-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little trycky, use [diff()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html), [cumsum()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) and [np.size](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.size.html) to find the size of the groups. Use [mask()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) to find groups smaller than 3 and replace those with [ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) and [bfill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html)

```
s = df.groupby((df['a'].diff() != 0).cumsum()).transform(np.size)
df['a'] = df[['a']].mask(s < 3).ffill().bfill()

#result
[8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.,
   4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 5., 5.,
   5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.,
   5., 5.]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `NumPy` will be useful as:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [8,8,0,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,
                          4,1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
                          4,4,7,7,4,4,4,4,4,4,
                          4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,1,1,
                          5,5,5,5,5,5,1,5,4,5,
                          5,5,5]})

arr = df.values.reshape(-1)
sub = arr[1:]-arr[:-1]
add2 = sub[1:]+sub[:-1]  
add3 = sub[2:]+sub[:-2]
del2 = np.where((sub[1:]!=0) & (add2*sub[1:]==0))[0]+1
del3 = np.where((sub[2:]!=0) & (add3*sub[2:]==0))[0]+1
arr[del2] = arr[del2-1]
arr[del3] = arr[del3-1]
arr[del3+1] = arr[del3+2]
df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : arr})
print(arr)

'''
Output:
[8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5
 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5]
'''
```