# Count consecutive boolean values in Python/pandas array for whole subset

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am looking for a way to aggregate pandas data frame by consecutive same values and perform actions like count or max on this aggregation.

for example, if I would have one column in df:

```
    my_column
0        0  
1        0  
2        1  
3        1  
4        1  
5        0  
6        0  
7        0  
8        0  
9        1  
10       1  
11       0
```

the result needs to be:

```
    result
0        2  
1        2  
2        3  
3        3  
4        3  
5        4  
6        4  
7        4  
8        4  
9        2  
10       2  
11       1
```

Why: We have two 0 at the beginning, and three 1 next,...

What I need, is similar that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626542/counting-consecutive-positive-values-in-python-pandas-array) but for all elements in the group I need the same value.

The preferred answer would be one that shows this aggregation of the consecutive same element and applies the aggregation function to it. So that I could do even max value:

```
    my_column    other_value
0        0           7
1        0           4
2        1           1
3        1           0
4        1           5
5        0           1
6        0           1
7        0           2
8        0           8
9        1           1
10       1           0
11       0           2
```

and the result would be

```
    result
0        7  
1        7  
2        5  
3        5  
4        5  
5        8  
6        8  
7        8  
8        8  
9        1  
10       1  
11       2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
g = df["my_column"].ne(df["my_column"].shift()).cumsum()

out = df.groupby(g)["my_column"].transform("count")
```

Output :

```
print(out)
​
    my_column
0           2
1           2
2           3
3           3
4           3
5           4
6           4
7           4
8           4
9           2
10          2
11          1
```

NB : to get the max, use `df.groupby(g)["other_value"].transform("max")`.

Answer (score 0):

If check [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626542/counting-consecutive-positive-values-in-python-pandas-array) there is exactly way for groups by consecutive values:

```
(y != y.shift()).cumsum()
```

So if create consecutive groups per column `my_column` output is:

```
g = df["my_column"].ne(df["my_column"].shift()).cumsum()

print (g)
0     1
1     1
2     2
3     2
4     2
5     3
6     3
7     3
8     3
9     4
10    4
11    5
Name: my_column, dtype: int32
```

is possible use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for count values per groups

If necessary one column `DataFrame` add [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html).

*Note: [`DataFrameGroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.count.html) is used for count values with omit missing values, here working because no `NaN`s*

```
df1 = df.groupby(g)['my_column'].transform('size').to_frame()
print (df1)
    my_column
0           2
1           2
2           3
3           3
4           3
5           4
6           4
7           4
8           4
9           2
10          2
11          1
```

Or [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df1 = g.map(g.value_counts()).to_frame()
print (df1)
    my_column
0           2
1           2
2           3
3           3
4           3
5           4
6           4
7           4
8           4
9           2
10          2
11          1
```

Similar way for second solution:

```
g = df["my_column"].ne(df["my_column"].shift()).cumsum()

df1 = df.groupby(g)['other_value'].transform('max').to_frame(name='result')
print (df1)
    result
0        7
1        7
2        5
3        5
4        5
5        8
6        8
7        8
8        8
9        1
10       1
11       2
```